# Trying to install Python3 using brew

Tags: python-3.x, homebrew

Trying to install Python3 in mac using below command :

```
brew install python3
```

When i run the command getting below error :

```
Error: python 2.7.14_2 is already installed
To upgrade to 3.6.5, run `brew upgrade python`
```

How to keep both python2 and python3 in mac without upgrading...

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `python` formula is assumed by Homebrew to be Python 3. The formula `python3` is thus an alias for `python`.

You need to:

1. `brew upgrade python`, as told by the error message. It will switch your default Homebrew Python from 2 to 3.
2. `brew install python@2`. It will install Python 2 alongside Python 3.

Note however that even with Python 3 installed (using the formula called `python`), the command `python` still points to Python 2. You need to either type `python3` to run Python 3, or add Homebrew’s Python 3 unprefixed `bin` directory at the beginning of your [`$PATH`](https://bfontaine.net/blog/2017/03/04/add-this-directory-to-your-path/):

```
export PATH="$(brew --prefix python)/libexec/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Is it possible to install both python 2 and python 3 and have `python` point to python 2 by default?

Comment: @Antimony The `python` binary points to `python2` by default ([see the docs here](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python)). I edited my answer to clarify this: `python` as a formula name (as in `brew install python`) is Python 3, but `python` as an executable (as in `python myscript.py`) is Python 2 by default.