# How Upgrade Python 3.7.2 to Python 3.7.3 via Homebrew

Tags: python

The problem is I already have the latest python on my Mac, but when I write `python3` in terminal, It shows `3.7.2`, not the latest i.e. `3.7.3` .

I Tried Using `brew link python3` and that doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to install Python3 using brew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49672642/trying-to-install-python3-using-brew)

Answer (score 1):

Try `brew upgrade python3` to update python3. If that doesn't work, try to `brew update` (to update Brew) before running the command

Comment: So did I, Homebrew said you have already latest version (3.7.3), But when I type python3 it shows me previews version (3.7.2). The problem is I want that it shows me 3.7.3 when I type python3.

Comment: I think that you have two instances of python3 installed on your Mac. Do you, by any means, have (or had) anaconda installed?

Comment: No, I didn't and neither virtualenv and ... . I just installed 3.7.2 in 2018. And it is still default of my python3.

Comment: Homebrew installs python3 in a separate location from the Mac's system-python (homebrew do not override system-python!). You have to tell the terminal, to run the homebrew python3 as default. Watch this thread for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49413504/brew-installed-python-not-overriding-system-python